# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tortoise.api'

Tags: python

I am getting this error when trying to run Tortoise TTS from this repo: https://git.ecker.tech/mrq/ai-voice-cloning. I have followed the installation instruction and ran `pip install -r requirements.txt` and `sudo pip install --upgrade tortoise.api`. What should I do to resolve this error? It happens after I run the main script with: `python3.9 ./src/main.py "$@"`.

Comment: Would you please the code that causes this error and the full error output?

Comment: Are you following directions from some site? If so, which one? What exactly is in your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: @JesseSealand This code: python3.9 ./src/main.py "$@"

Comment: Please post the full error output. This includes the stack trace, not just one line but the whole thing.

Comment: @JesseSealand I have resolved this issue by using python3.9. Now Im getting a new error: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psutil_windows: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.